# CUDNN ERROR: Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: ubuntu, python, cuda

I'm having trouble running convolution networks on Keras with a source-compiled Tensorflow build. I'm using CUDA 10.0 and CuDNN 7.4 and both have been correctly compiled, as verified by their example makefiles. I end up getting these errors when I run a conv net but not a dense network:

```
UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
 [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
 [[metrics/acc/Mean/_169]]
```

I've tried appending the paths to CUDA and CuDNN directly to my path, tried reinstalling and recompiling TensorFlow with no results. There shouldn't be any issues with conflicting versions as this is a fresh install on this machine.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.datasets import mnist
import sys

def one_hot(data, num_categories):
    oh = np.zeros((len(data),num_categories))
    for i,entry in enumerate(data):
        oh[i, entry] = 1
    return oh


# import data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# preprocess data
x_train = x_train.reshape( (60000,28,28,1) ) / 256
x_test = x_test.reshape( (10000,28,28,1) ) / 256
y_train = one_hot(y_train, 10)
y_test = one_hot(y_test, 10)

# build the model
model = Sequential()
input_shape=(28,28,1)
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,
                 kernel_size=(3,3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                       strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,
                 kernel_size=(3,3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                       strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=256,
                activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=10,
                activation='softmax'))

# load model weight

# compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# train
num_epochs = 20
if num_epochs != 0:
    # train the model
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=32,
              epochs=num_epochs)

# evaluate model
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('\nScore: ', score)
```

The code I'm running works perfectly well on my laptop which does not have a dedicated GPU, but I'm attempting to get CUDA/CuDNN up and running on this desktop. Any help diagnosing this issue would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: It seems there might be an error related to using the default NCCL as opposed to the newest version when building TF from source. I am attempting to install the OS-agnostic version of the most recent NCCL. This is bringing a new error: ldconfig lists NCCL, but cannot find it's libraries. This makes it impossible for me to build from source with the latest NCCL, so I cannot see if this is the root cause yet.

Comment: Did you fixed this error?

Comment: Did you fix it? @spicyramen, @BranchedOut?

Comment: Yes, it was 2 issues on my side, incorrect version of drivers and also my TF was using all memory in GPU and there were 2 simultaneous TF running hence I needed to restrict GPU utilization in TF configuration

Comment: "I end up getting these errors when I run a conv net but not a dense network". fyi, I have observed a very similar issue where a network consisting of only a `Conv3D` layer fails, but adding a `Dense` layer fixed the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872336/cudnn-status-alloc-failed-with-minimal-network-and-data. I will try out updating/reinstalling all drivers (although I am using a freshly installed system just was you were).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this error message for three different reasons, with different solutions:

## 1. You have cache issues

I regularly work around this error by shutting down my python process, removing the `~/.nv` directory (on linux, `rm -rf ~/.nv`), and restarting the Python process. I don't exactly know why this works. It's probably at least partly related to the second option:

## 3. You're out of memory

The error can also show up if you run out of graphics card RAM. With an nvidia GPU you can check graphics card memory usage with `nvidia-smi`. This will give you not only a readout of how much GPU RAM you have in use (something like `6025MiB /  6086MiB` if you're almost at the limit) as well as a list of what processes are using GPU RAM.

If you've run out of RAM, you'll need to restart the process (which should free up the RAM) and then take a less memory-intensive approach. A few options are:

- reducing your batch size
- using a simpler model
- using less data
- limit TensorFlow GPU memory fraction: For example, the following will make sure TensorFlow uses <= 90% of your RAM:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

This will likely slow down your model evaluation if not used together with the items above.

## 3. You have incompatible versions of CUDA, TensorFlow, NVIDIA drivers etc.

If you've never had similar models working, you're not running out of VRAM **and** your cache is clean, I'd go back and set up CUDA + TensorFlow using the best available installation guide - I have had the most success with following the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu rather than those on the NVIDIA / CUDA site.

Comment: That definitely solved my problem. For me the issue was #3, and reinstalling all CUDA-related software was the fix

Answer (score 0):

Just add where importing tensorflow

Working for tensorflow=1.*

```python
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto()

config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Consider using the code-formatting options for clarity (click the ? in the toolbar when editing your post to see details). One option is a line of triple backticks above and below the code block.

Answer (score -1):

Using Jupyter notebook and running multiple notebooks at the same time causes you GPU(s) memory to fill up, all I did was shutdown some of the notebook kernels I wasn't using.